# Throw keyword in Java

Tags: java, exception, throw, throws

In Java, is the keyword (throw) only used for throwing exception that you've created. If not, can someone give an example of how it is used outside of your own made exceptions.

Comment: `throw new IllegalArgumentException("whatever");`

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: How could the JVM possibly know who created the exception class? Question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `throw` anything that extends `Throwable`

```
void greet(String name) {
    if (name == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot greet null");
    }
    System.out.println("Hello, " + name);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, the `throw` keyword can be used with *any* `Exception`, including built-in ones:

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("Your value passed in was illegal");
```

Answer (score 2):

As mention in [JLS 14.18](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.18)

> The Expression in a throw statement must denote either *1) a variable
>   or value of a reference type which is assignable (§5.2) to the type
>   **Throwable**, or 2) the null reference*, or a compile-time error occurs.

For example Consider the situation given below:

```
public void factorial(int num)
{
    if (num < 0 )
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid number :"+num);
    }
    else
        //....code for factorial.
}
```

Here [`IllegalArgumentException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) is not the user defined exception. It is a built in `RunTimeException` and as specified in oracle docs:

> Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or
>   inappropriate argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can throw anything that extends `Throwable` including errors, your exceptions, and the java builtin exceptions.

It can also be used for more complex logic:

You can use it to rethrow, for example,  `ThreadDeathErrors` among other exceptions. When a thread must die, it can catch this error:

```
catch(ThreadDeathError e){
    System.out.println("Thread going down");
    throw e;
}
```

Here, `e` is not your own exception, but an error that was caught. Please respect the differences between errors and exceptions as the former are not generally caught.

The thread death error must be rethrown to actually cause the theread to die.

Answer (score 0):

throw can be used to thow any exception that extends java.lang.Throwable